# ANTL4 Grammar compile Nullpointer Exception

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4, tagging

In gereral I am trying to create a Java based application, where I can *compile* a dictionary of terms which supports simple regular expressions. The dictionary will then be used to create a simple entity **tagger**, where a recognised term is marked in a text. Thought that ANTLR might provide all I need. Trying to create a Java application which does not depend on the compiled grammar and lexer files, since the grammar has to be updated in runtime every few minutes.

Here my simple "Hello World" application:

```
LexerGrammar lg = new LexerGrammar(
                "lexer grammar L;\n" +
                "A : ('a'|'A');\n" +
                "B : ('b'|'B');\n" +
                "C : ('c'|'C');\n" +
                "D : ('d'|'D');\n" +
                "FILL_TOKEN : (.);\n");

Grammar g = new Grammar(
                "parser grammar T;\n" +
                "t_abc : A FILL_TOKEN? B FILL_TOKEN? C;\n" +
                "t_abcd : A FILL_TOKEN? B FILL_TOKEN? C FILL_TOKEN? D;\n" +

                "rule0   : t_abcd|t_abc;\n" +

                "ws  : '.' -> skip ;\n",
                lg);

LexerInterpreter lexEngine =
                lg.createLexerInterpreter(new ANTLRInputStream("Test A BCD"));
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexEngine);
ParserInterpreter parser = g.createParserInterpreter(tokens);
Rule rule = g.rules.get("rule0");
ParseTree t = parser.parse(rule.index);

System.out.println(t.getText());
```

When I try to compile the application, I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNSerializer.serialize(ATNSerializer.java:73)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNSerializer.getSerialized(ATNSerializer.java:601)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNSerializer.getSerializedAsChars(ATNSerializer.java:605)
    at org.antlr.v4.tool.Grammar.createParserInterpreter(Grammar.java:1337)
    at main.OnTheFly.main(OnTheFly.java:98)
```

When I comment out the `"ws  : '.' -> skip ;\n",` part of the grammar, the program runs, but it complains that `Test` is not known.

What I am doing wrong or does the default grammar not support the `skip` parameter?
Using Antlr 4.7.2 and Java 1.8.0 (131)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. Only the lexer supports the `skip` parameter and in addition, I only required the lexer all together. The matches can be retrieved, by looking at the result tokens:

```
... 
// using code from above with grammar part, including SKIP rule.
// In additions, all tokens have to be defined in
// ...

// required to process the input stream
tokens.fill();
for (Token token : tokens.getTokens()) {                
    int typeId = token.getType();
    if (-1 == typeId) {
        break;
    }

    String ruleName = lexEngine.getRuleNames()[token.getType() - 1];
    System.out.println("Token: " + token.getText() + " - " +   ruleName);
}
```

More information about the lexer and grammar vocabulary can be found here:

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md